# How to switch paper orientation in Libre office 5? (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, printing, libreoffice, orientation

I have to print a table from Calc...

I need to:

1. switch it to landscape orientation
2. combine all 6 pages in one (because it is one table)

[image]

but according to the screenshot I can print only portrait orientation and on 6 separate pages...

How can I get what I want?

If you need more screenshots or anything else, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first you should open the page settings by path **Format-Page-Sheet** and change **"Scaling mode"** to **"Fit print range(s) to width/height"**. In the same tab settings open tab **"Page"** and replace mark from **"Portrait"** to **"Landscape"**. Save changes. All must be working good:)
If nothing helps you can open "LibreOffice Help", use F1 and select "landscape printing".

Comment: could you please help me to find **Format** icon? Just look at my sceenshot and say whith exact icon is **Format** ?

Comment: Use shortcut "Alt+O"